# Inline ASM: Use of MMX returns NaN seconds on timer

Tags: performance, gcc, time, inline-assembly, mmx

**Problem**

I am trying to find out whether `mmx` or `xmm` registers are faster for copying elements of an array to another array (I know about `memcpy()` but I need this function for a very specific purpose).

My souce code is below. The relevant function is `copyarray()`. I can use either `mmx` or `xmm` registers with `movq` or `movsd` respectively, and the result is correct. However, when I use `mmx` registers, any timer I use (either `clock()` or `QueryPerformanceCounter`) to time the operations returns `NaN`.

Compiled with: `gcc -std=c99 -O2 -m32 -msse3 -mincoming-stack-boundary=2 -mfpmath=sse,387 -masm=intel copyasm.c -o copyasm.exe`

**This is a very strange bug and I cannot figure out why using `mmx` registers would cause a timer to return `NaN` seconds, while using `xmm` registers in exactly the same code returns a valid time value**

**EDIT**

Results using `xmm` registers:

```
Elapsed time: 0.000000 seconds, Gigabytes copied per second: inf GB
Residual = 0.000000
  0.937437    0.330424    0.883267    0.118717    0.962493    0.584826    0.344371    0.423719
  0.937437    0.330424    0.883267    0.118717    0.962493    0.584826    0.344371    0.423719
```

Results using `mmx` register:

```
Elapsed time: nan seconds, Gigabytes copied per second: inf GB
Residual = 0.000000
  0.000000    0.754173    0.615345    0.634724    0.611286    0.547655    0.729637    0.942381
  0.935759    0.754173    0.615345    0.634724    0.611286    0.547655    0.729637    0.942381
```

**Source Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <windows.h>

inline double 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64))) copyarray(
            double* restrict dst,
            const double* restrict src,
            const int n)
{
    // int i = n;
    // do {
        // *dst++ = *src++;
        // i--;
        // } while(i);

            __asm__ __volatile__
            (
                "mov    ecx, %[n]                   \n\t"
                "mov    edi, %[dst]                 \n\t"
                "mov    esi, %[src]                 \n\t"
                "xor    eax, eax                    \n\t"
                "sub    ecx,1                       \n\t"
                "L%=:                               \n\t"
                "movq   mm0, QWORD PTR [esi+ecx*8]  \n\t"
                "movq   QWORD PTR [edi+ecx*8], mm0  \n\t"
                "sub    ecx, 1                      \n\t"
                "jge    L%=                         \n\t"
                : // no outputs
                : // inputs
                [dst] "m" (dst),
                [src] "m" (src),
                [n] "g" (n)
                : // register clobber
                "eax","ecx","edi","esi",
                "mm0"
            );
}

void printarray(double* restrict a, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("  %f  ", *(a++));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

double residual(const double* restrict dst,
                const double* restrict src,
                const int n)
{
    double residual = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        residual += *(dst++) - *(src++);

    return(residual);
}

int main()
{
    double *A = NULL;
    double *B = NULL;
    int n = 8;
    double memops;
    double time3;
    clock_t time1;
    // LARGE_INTEGER frequency, time1, time2;
    // QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    int trials = 1 << 0;


    A = _mm_malloc(n*sizeof(*A), 64);
    B = _mm_malloc(n*sizeof(*B), 64);

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        *(A+i) = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;

            // QueryPerformanceCounter(&time1);

    time1 = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
        copyarray(B,A,n);

        // QueryPerformanceCounter(&time2);

    // time3 = (double)(time2.QuadPart - time1.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;
    time3 = (double) (clock() - time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    memops = (double) trials*n/time3*sizeof(*A)/1.0e9;
    printf("Elapsed time: %f seconds, Gigabytes copied per second: %f GB\n",time3, memops);
    printf("Residual = %f\n",residual(B,A,n));
    printarray(A,n);
    printarray(B,n);

    _mm_free(A);
    _mm_free(B);
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful when mixing MMX with floating point. Use SSE instead.

Comment: @PaulR, what would be the issue? Aren't the MMX registers a subset of the x87 floating point registers?

Comment: This is ancient history now (MMX is 15+ years behind the times), but I believe there are rules you need to follow when mixing MMX and floating point instructions - let me see if I can Google this...

Comment: OK - read the section titled "MMX - State Management" on [this page](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/mmx.php) - note the requirement for the `emms` instruction after any MMX instructions before you next perform any floating point operations.

Comment: @PaulR Cool thnx....now I can time my MMX registers. And I see there is no speed benefit to using MMX over XMM for copies. I can accept your comment as an answer if you want to copy paste.

Comment: OK - glad that helps - I've converted the comments above to an answer now, as you suggest.

Comment: The MMX registers are aliased to the FP registers. So using one will corrupt the other.

Comment: I know this is just test code, but you could do slightly better: 1) Change the constraints for src & dst to "S" & "D", omit the MOVs and clobbers, change all refs to %[src]/%[dst]. The compiler will move the ptrs in at a convenient time & can re-use them in other code. 2) Make n an output and use "+r" (omit MOV & clobber, change ecx to %[n]). Lets the compiler pick a scratch reg. 3) Important: Since you are reading+writing memory & changing flags, these should be clobbered. Looks like with a little work, this can become 5 asm instructions and only this for clobbers: "cc","memory","mm0".  FWIW.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd TY for the pointers, I will give them a try sometime in the next couple of days. I will post some more results then (maybe there will be a speedup).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, Is there a constraint that would generate `XMMWORD PTR`? Say if i wanted to copy a vector at a time. I tried `'xm'` but it just generates `DWORD PTR`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean.  The official list of i386-specific constraints can be found at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html (search for i386).  It is also possible to do `movdqa %[temp], XMMWORD PTR [%[src]+%q[n]*8]` where temp is defined as `[temp] "=x" (temp)`.  This generates `movdqa xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdx*8]`.  Obviously this is x64.  Change '%q[n]' to '%[n]' for 32bit.

Comment: I had `movapd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [%[eax]]` in one code and it compiled into `movapd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [DWORD PTR [esp+20]]`

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, forgot to notify you.

Comment: @matmul, see Agner Fog's asmlib http://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib.  It's a collection of basic functions written in assembly.  The memcpy assembly code will probably be interesting to you.

Comment: I'm not sure what %[eax] is supposed to mean.  Was that supposed to be %%eax?  Or [%%eax]?  %[dst]?  I'd need to see the actual code and asm parameters.  At a wild guess, try changing the constraint (whatever it is) from "m" to "r".

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, yes sorry I meant `%[dst]`. I tried `m`, `r`, `g`, `x`, `xm`, and `mx`. I will post the code sample shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful when mixing MMX with floating point - use SSE instead if possible. If you *must* use MMX then read the section titled "MMX - State Management" on [this page](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/mmx.php) - note the requirement for the [emms instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/590b9ks9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) after any MMX instructions before you next perform any floating point operations.